# Call function directly from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to call a PHP function via an array like so:

```
$x = (object) array(
    "one" => "value",
    "two" => "value2",
    "three" => function() {
        return "return_value";
    }
);

echo($x->three());
```

From this I receive the error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method stdClass::three()
```

I've searched a bit and cannot find any documentation on this, however I ran this through

```
php -l filename.php
```

which found no syntax errors.

I would like to know if what I'm trying to do is possible (end goal is to call a function with parameters from an array).
Is anybody able to shed some light on this?

Thanks

Note, I have also tried:

```
function foo() {
    return "bar";
}
$x = (object) array(
    "foo" => foo
);
...
```

which leads to the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of method you created is classified as an anonymous function and is represented by the [Closure](http://php.net/Closure) class and thus inherits its properties, which includes the invoke method as specified by Amal Murali.

You have two ways of calling this function:

1. `echo $x->three->__invoke();`
2. `echo call_user_func( $x->three );`

If you need to pass arguments, you can call `$x->three->__invoke( $args );` or `call_user_func( $x->three, $args1, $args2 );`.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array instead of an object:

```
$x = array(
    "one" => "value",
    "two" => "value2",
    "three" => function() {
        return "return_value";
    }
);
```

To call the lambda function, you can do:

```
echo $x['three']();
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/111643)

---

If you really must use an object, then you can do the following:

```
$x = array(
    "one" => "value",
    "two" => "value2",
);

$obj = (object) $x;
$obj->three = function() {
    return "return_value";
};
```

To call the function:

```
echo $obj->three->__invoke();
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/111658)